# Cakephp 2.1 rename ACL Table without ACL Model

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I have trouble using ACL. In my CoreUsersController i make the following call:

```
if(!$this->Acl->check('User::'.$user['User']['id'], 'CoreUser', 'read')) {
    die('PERM DENIED');
}
```

The ACL is included as component in my AppController. The Database-Tables looks like:

- table "acos"
- table "core_groups" (as aros)
- table "aros_acos" as connection between core_groups and acos.

---

**Here is the Error Thrown:**
*Error: Table aros for model Aro was not found in datasource default.*

---

**And my Code:**

**1. User-Model:**

```
    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

    class CoreUser extends AppModel {

            public $useDbConfig = 'default';
            public $useTable    = 'core_users';

            public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
                'MemberOf' => array(
                    'className' => 'CoreGroup',
                    'joinTable' => 'core_users_groups',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                    'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id'
                )
            );

            public $name = 'User';
            public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'both'));

            public function parentNode() {
                // stuff in here should be correct
            }
```

}

**2. Group-Model:**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class CoreGroup extends AppModel {

        public $useDbConfig = 'default';
        public $useTable    = 'core_groups';

        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Member' => array(
                'className' => 'CoreUser',
                'joinTable' => 'core_users_groups',
                'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
            )
        );
        public $name = 'Group';
        public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

        public function parentNode() {
            return null;
        }
}
```

---

**My Question:** How to tell ACL to use "core_groups"-Table instead of "aros"-table? Note: I added "ActsAs" as suggested by the Cake-Book to both Models!

Comment: Did you use this command in shell: ./Console/cake schema create DbAcl to create acl tables or you did that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to proceed with Cake's ACL, then it is better to have three separate tables:

```
1. aros
2. acos
3. aros_acos
```

These can be generated using the AclShell:

```
./Console/cake schema create DbAcl
```

Using one of your app's model as an ARO or ACO is not advised as ARO and ACO models are implemented as a tree structure. These should be separate from the models in your app that 'actsAs' an ACO / ARO.

When you do attach the Acl behavior in the `$actsAs` property to your User/Group models, the Acl behavior's callbacks kick in. These use the `parentNode()` methods defined in your User/Group models to create an ARO **reference** to the rows created in your User/Group models. These references are **stored in the ARO** table separately, pointing to the actual User and Group. Hence, the ARO table is necessary.

I would recommend you go through [the ACL tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#simple-acl-controlled-application) in the book as your implementation will be quite similar. Just be careful about using the HABTM relationship between User and Group, as that will need a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply! I read the (many) ACL Tutorials, ech several times but its hard for me to get it, since most of the tutorials are theory-only and there is not a (full, deep-nested) example-app..

Comment: The tutorial in the book does nest a User ARO within a Group ARO. The only difference in your case is the relationship between User and Group. Regardless, the fact remains that you should use a separate aros table for the reasons mentioned in my answer. You can refer to the [core ARO model](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Aro.html) and see that your CoreGroup model table will not be able to replicate the functionality of behaving like a tree, etc. Try and use a separate table and let us know if you have any other questions/errors. Good luck.